# In Google Angular Map api, how to get places details using place_id?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to get places information [like this example](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?key=AIzaSyDMJVEN6yD_nfxWGsOZttouWAFBHczbh0w&placeid=ChIJLfyY2E4UrjsRVq4AjI7zgRY) location, city, State, longitude, latitude, formatted_address using place_id. I am getting error **Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function**. I am using [this: places/place-id](https://developers.google.com/places/place-id) google api for getting address. There are using map variable inside `var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);` Because I am using angular-google-map, so I am passing `$scope.map` as parameter instead of `map`. Please check the following code, where I am wrong, I am error due to passing `$scope.map` in `PlacesService` which is expecting `map` as parameter in [this example](https://developers.google.com/places/place-id).

**HTML**

```
<ui-gmap-google-map center='map.center' zoom='map.zoom' control='map.control' id="map-canvas">
  <ui-gmap-markers models="markers" idkey="markers.id" coords="'coords'" >

  </ui-gmap-markers>
</ui-gmap-google-map>
```

**Controller**

```
 var map={
       center: {
         latitude: 
         longitude: 
       },
       bounds : ,
       zoom: 5,
       control : {}
    };
    $scope.map = map;

 var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService($scope.map);
 service.getDetails({ placeId: $scope.place_id}, function(place, status){
          console.log('place='+place);
 });
```

Comment: Where did you get the "undefined is not a function"? Can you paste the Error trace?

Comment: @ZhenyangHua I am getting define due to I am using $scope.map in PlacesService.........

Comment: `PlacesService(attrContainer:HTMLDivElement | Map)`, the $scope.map is just an object literal, it is not a `Map` type or a DOM. To get a `Map` type object, use `$scope.map.control.getMap()` and parse it into the `PlacesService(map)` method.

Comment: @ZhenyangHua Thanks for reply, are you telling like `var map=$scope.map.control.getMap() then place inside PlacesService(map)`

Comment: @ZhenyangHua I will appreciate if you give explanation in answer part...

Comment: Yes. http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/api/google-map, in the control parameter, it says to get the map instance, you need to call `$scope.map.control.getMap()`.

Comment: @ZhenyangHua I tried this but still getting this error....

Comment: `$log.log($scope.map.control.getMap());` What's logged?

Comment: @ZhenyangHua   correct syntax is   `var map=$scope.map.control.getGMap() `. You forget 'G' letter.....

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments above, `var map=$scope.map.control.getGMap()` is the solution.

So for others who use angular-google-map, you need to use `$scope.map.control.getGMap()` to get the current map instance.